# vue.js dynamic image load

Tags: javascript, vue.js, require

I'm trying to load images dynamically from data returned in an ajax request.
The images are in my local src/assets folder and the component that is trying to load it is in the src/components folder. The url that I get back from the server is: (for example) "/assets/topics/dogs.png".
When I call the img with
`<img src="../assets/topics/dogs.png" />`
it works, but when I try to load it dynamically it fails. I tried using require but I get an error: Cannot find module '../assets/topics/dogs.png' at webpackEmptyContext.
This is my code:

```
<template>
  <div class="activity-wrapper">
    <div class="info">
      <span class="icon"><img :src="feedItemIcon" /></span>
    </div>
    <div class="actions"></div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Activity',
  props: ['activity'],
  computed: {
    feedItemIcon() {
      return require( `..${this.activity.topic_data.icon_path}`);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: If you are passing activity as a prop. You can directly use ```computed: {
feedItemIcon() {
      return this.activity.topic_data.icon_path;
    }
  }``` Why do you want to use require here?

Comment: @AbhimanuSharma I tried that first, the images are broken.
when I hardcode it and look at the generated code in the browser I get this: ```<img src="/img/cells.20667cdb.png">``` instead of ```<img src="../assets/topics/cells.png" />```

Comment: Remove `../assets/` from the variable path and hardcode it:  `require('@/assets/' + this.activity.topic_data.icon_path)`

Comment: @Dan that didn't work, but ```return require(`../assets${path}`);``` did, I don't understand, it's the same path as before, why is it working now?

Comment: In Vue CLI, `@/assets` is equivalent to `src/assets` from any relative path. You may have forgotten to remove the `/assets` portion of the path from the variable when trying what I suggested.  Either way, sometimes webpack has trouble with `require` when you do unusual things with a variable path (such as the leading `..` + variable).  I thought this was fixed in recent versions, and I can't reproduce the error you got in current CLI